# Negative numbers in if statement

Tags: php

Negative number explanation.

I have this:

```
$start_ts1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$end_ts1 = strtotime($app_date);
$diff1 = $end_ts1 - $start_ts1;
$DIFF1 = round($diff1 / 86400);
```

This does return a negative number (working correctly) but I am have a brain fart on doing the if statement.

I have this:

```
if($DIFF1 <= 0) {
    //do when it is negative
} else {
    //else if false
}
```

Usually less then or equal too is negative. Is this correct?

Comment: Are you saying `$DIFF1` is negative, but the `else` branch is executed? If so, then no, that shouldn't happen. But I don't see anything there that indicates why it would happen.

Comment: _less then or equal too is negative_ No, less than 0 is negative, equal to 0 is 0.

Comment: Do you have to do anything special if the DIFF is exactly zero? Or ONLY if its truly negative?

Comment: Yes $DIFF1 is negative. 
If it is negative I want to shoe something different. 
Hopefully I make sense.

Comment: BTW only if it is truly negative

Comment: do you wants to get days diff. in number from two days?

Answer (score 0):

0 is not considered negative. Use "<" in the if instead.

```
if($DIFF1 < 0) {
//case for negative difference
} else {
//case for 0 or positive difference
}
```

Comment: Let me add to what I have here:
$start_ts1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$end_ts1 = strtotime($app_date);
$diff1 = $end_ts1 - $start_ts1;
$DIFF1 = round($diff1 / 86400);

that is returning the negative numbers, which I want.

Comment: This is not the behavior I'm encountering please see [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C%3Fphp%5Cnfunction%20caseDiff%28%24diff%29%20%7B%5Cn%20if%28%24diff%20%3C%200%29%20%7B%5Cn%20return%20%22Negative%5Cn%22%3B%5Cn%20%7D%20else%20%7B%5Cn%20return%20%22Positive%5Cn%22%3B%5Cn%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cnecho%20caseDiff%28-1%29%3B%5Cnecho%20caseDiff%280%29%3B%5Cnecho%20caseDiff%28-0%29%3B%5Cnecho%20caseDiff%281%29%3B%5Cn%5Cn%3F%3E%5Cn)